# Check same element in every subarray

Tags: php, cakephp

I stuck a bit with this array so I appreciate any solution, comment, anything. I have array like this:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>array(1) {
        ["ToursPrices"]=>array(1) {
            ["forced"]=>string(1) "1"
        }
    }
    [1]=>array(1) {
        ["ToursPrices"]=>array(1) {
            ["forced"]=>string(1) "0"
        }
    }
    [2]=>array(1) {
        ["ToursPrices"]=>array(1) {
            ["forced"]=>string(1) "0"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to check `forced` element to see if all `forced` elements have value "1". If all of them have value "1" I need to set `$all_forced = true`, else I need to set `$all_forced = false`. Any ideas how can I do that? Thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: Ugh, I really wish there was an automatic `print_r()` to `var_export()` feature on the site.

Comment: Set `$all_forced = true`, Perform a loop, check if each `$arr["ToursPrices"]["forced"]` is 1. If it isn't, set `$all_forced = false` and break out of the loop.

Comment: @MLeFevre thanks for idea, I'll do that definitely.

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_forced = true;

        $d = array(
            array('ToursPrices'=> array('forced'=>1)),
            array('ToursPrices'=> array('forced'=>1)),
            array('ToursPrices'=> array('forced'=>0)),
        );

        foreach($d as $el){
            if(!$el['ToursPrices']['forced']){
                $all_forced = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        debug($all_forced);
```